# convert array to one variable with multiple values

Tags: php

here is my array .

```
 $myarray = Array
 (
 [0] = Array
(
    [name] = 17
)

   [1] = Array
(
    [name] = 18
)

   [2] = Array
(
    [name] = 19
)

 )
```

I want `myvar` to return this '17,18,19'

```
$var = '17,18,19';
```

Comment: [array_column](http://php.net/array_column) and [implode](http://php.net/implode).

Comment: can you give this array in json format? and What have you done so far?

Comment: works jonnix thanks :)

Comment: Please use `implode(', ', array_column($myarray, 'name'));`

Answer (score 0):

You can use [array_map](http://docs.php.net/manual/da/function.array-map.php);

```
$temp = array_map(function($i){return $i['name'];}, $myarray); 

$output = implode(',', $temp);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in many ways. One way to do it with `array_column()` and `implode()`

```
<?php
$myarray = array(array('name' => 17),array('name' => 18),array('name' => 19));
$one_d = array_column($myarray, 'name');
echo implode(',',$one_d);
?>
```

**DEMO:** https://3v4l.org/rCmKR

Answer (score 0):

A simple `foreach` could also do the trick.

```php
$var = '';
foreach ($myarray as $value) {
    $var .= $value['name'].',';
}
$var = substr($var, 0, -1);
echo $var; // 17,18,19
```